# How to use Blocks correctly to load AWS S3 credentials in Prefect?

Tags: python, prefect

I am using Prefect. And I tried to download a file from S3.

When I hard coded the AWS credentials, the file can be downloaded successfully:

```
import asyncio

from prefect_aws.s3 import s3_download
from prefect_aws.credentials import AwsCredentials

from prefect import flow, get_run_logger


@flow
async def fetch_taxi_data():
    logger = get_run_logger()
    credentials = AwsCredentials(
        aws_access_key_id="xxx",
        aws_secret_access_key="xxx",
    )
    data = await s3_download(
        bucket="hongbomiao-bucket",
        key="hm-airflow/taxi.csv",
        aws_credentials=credentials,
    )
    logger.info(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(fetch_taxi_data())
```

Now I tried to load the credentials from [Prefect Blocks](https://docs.prefect.io/concepts/blocks/).

I created a AWS Credentials Block:

[image]

However,

```
aws_credentials_block = AwsCredentials.load("aws-credentials-block")
data = await s3_download(
    bucket="hongbomiao-bucket",
    key="hm-airflow/taxi.csv",
    aws_credentials=aws_credentials_block,
)
```

throws the error:

> AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'get_boto3_session'

And

```
aws_credentials_block = AwsCredentials.load("aws-credentials-block")
credentials = AwsCredentials(
    aws_access_key_id=aws_credentials_block.aws_access_key_id,
    aws_secret_access_key=aws_credentials_block.aws_secret_access_key,
)
data = await s3_download(
    bucket="hongbomiao-bucket",
    key="hm-airflow/taxi.csv",
    aws_credentials=credentials,
)
```

throws the error:

> AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'aws_access_key_id'

I didn't find any useful document about how to use it.

Am I supposed to use Blocks to load credentials? If it is, what is the correct way to use Blocks correctly in Prefect? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the snippet in the screenshot in the question misses an `await`.

After adding `await`, it works now!

```
aws_credentials_block = await AwsCredentials.load("aws-credentials-block")
data = await s3_download(
    bucket="hongbomiao-bucket",
    key="hm-airflow/taxi.csv",
    aws_credentials=aws_credentials_block,
)
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Got an answer from Michael Adkins on [GitHub](https://github.com/PrefectHQ/prefect/issues/6994#issuecomment-1260064641), and thanks!

> `await` is only needed if you're writing an async flow or task. For users writing synchronous code, an `await` is not needed (and not possible). Most of our users are writing synchronous code and the example in the UI is in a synchronous context so it does not include the await.

I saw the source code at

https://github.com/PrefectHQ/prefect/blob/1dcd45637914896c60b7d49254a34e95a9ce56ea/src/prefect/blocks/core.py#L601-L604

```
@classmethod
@sync_compatible
@inject_client
async def load(cls, name: str, client: "OrionClient" = None):
    # ...
```

So I think as long as the function has the decorator `@sync_compatible`, it means it can be used as both async and sync functions.